# MVC route attribute no controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building an intranet where I have the following home controller:

```
[Route("{action=index}")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(HomeModelBuilder.BuildHomeModel());
    }

    public ActionResult FormsHome()
    {
        return View(HomeModelBuilder.BuildFormsHomeModel());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get my forms homepage to have a url of `http://intranet/forms` so I thought I could do this using the following routing attribute:

```
    [Route("~/forms")] // have also tried 'forms' and '/forms'
    public ActionResult FormsHome()
```

but when I go to the url, it complains that multiple controllers have that route:

> The request has found the following matching controller types: 
>   HRWebForms.Website.Controllers.ChangeDetailsController
>   HRWebForms.Website.Controllers.InternalTransferController
>   HRWebForms.Website.Controllers.LeaverController
>   ...

I have also tried adding `[RoutePrefix("")]` to the controller but this didn't work either

Is there a way to give that action a url of "forms" (without any controller or without adding a separate forms controller with an index) by just using routing attributes?

Comment: Show your route configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so ranquild's comment pushed me in the right direction.  In my route config, I had the default route of

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So that my homepage would still work on the url with nothing in.  If I changed this to

```
// Needed for homepage
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

// Needed for Html.ActionLink to work
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = UrlParameter.Optional, action = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It seemed to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding [RoutePrefix("forms")] to your controller, but this will result in all your actions expecting the same prefix.

There is a walkaround for this too (by using [Route("~/RouteParam/AnotherRouteParam")] to have Route "RouteParam/AnotherRouteParam") but it seems to me that FormsController would cost less work.